# Visual Studio F5 and Ctrl+F5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have strange problem here. I am using Visual Studio 2010. When I debug my code using <kbd>F5</kbd>, I am getting error. But without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) code runs fine. So can anyone tell me what is the problem, what is the difference between both of them and how to overcome the problem?

Comment: error messages aren't just random strings of words - even if you're not sure what the specific error message is saying, including the text of the message in your question would surely help others in locating the problem for you?

Comment: This is pretty normal, particularly for threading bugs.  Fix the bug.

Comment: @lc,@Damien_The_Unbeliever I dont find any error just closing the programme thats all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess (cause you are no giving that much details) when you are talking about erros you are probably talking about exceptions right ?
The fact is when you are running your project with CTRL+F5 you are running WITHOUT debugging, and F5 "debugging".

So if you are facing exceptions while "debugging" and not while "not debugging" it seems to mean that those exceptions are properly catched. One way to get rid of those exceptions is to check within the Debug Menu / then Exceptions and to check that all "Thrown" checkboxes are unchecked. This Exception window is there to force debug process to break in case of Exception even if they are properly catched.

Hope this helps.